# SQL запрос проверить все записи

Tags: sql, sqlite

`UPDATE maps SET state = @state WHERE id = (SELECT map FROM markers WHERE state = @markerstate)`

SELECT возвращает первую запись а мне нужно получить map если у всех записей с таким map state = @markerstate
Как проверить в sqlite?

Comment: Нет, `select` возвращает _набор_ данных, а не первую запись. Полагаю, вам нужно `... id in (select ...`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а что-нибудь побыстрее/менее прожорливое, чем `IN` придумать тут не получится?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE maps SET state = @state
 WHERE id IN (SELECT map FROM markers
               GROUP BY map
              HAVING max(state) = @markerstate and min(state)=@markerstate
             )
```

Подзапрос даст все map, для которых встречаются только записи с state=@markerstate.